# JDialog.dispose() closes box but not the app. Clicking the corner cross closes both

Tags: java, netbeans, jdialog

NetBeans 12.3 / Java 15.0.2 / Ubuntu 16.04.

I created a Maven/Java app in NetBeans having just a JDialog with a single button which calls dispose(). Run it in NetBeans. If I close it with the cross in the corner, the dialog goes and the app closes/exits. When I close it with the button, the dialog goes but the app never completes.

There is a window listener for close on the dialog (created by NetBeans). The listener calls `System.exit(0)`. Using debug I can see that the listener gets executed in the one case but not the other.  The dialog default close operation is dispose.

Of course I can just add a call `System.exit`, but I was under the impression there should be no  difference between dispose and closing the dialog with a corner cross?

```java
public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJDialog
     */
    public NewJDialog (java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super (parent, modal);
        initComponents ();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

      button1 = new java.awt.Button();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

      button1.setLabel("button1");
      button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            button1ActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(261, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(button1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(73, 73, 73))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(174, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(button1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(103, 103, 103))
      );

      pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
      dispose ();
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels ())
                if ("Nimbus".equals (info.getName ())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel (info.getClassName ());
                    break;
                }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger (NewJDialog.class.getName ()).log (java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger (NewJDialog.class.getName ()).log (java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger (NewJDialog.class.getName ()).log (java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger (NewJDialog.class.getName ()).log (java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the dialog
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            public void run () {
                NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog (new javax.swing.JFrame (), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener (new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter () {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing (java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit (0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible (true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.awt.Button button1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Documentation is your friend.  Read about [what dispose() does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) and [when windowClosing is called](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29).  dispose() merely destroys the window, which is why it is one of many possible default close operations.  dispose() does not simulate a press of the close button in the system-provided window controls.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the action listener to windowClosed rather than windowClosing fixes it (catches both types of close). As VGR points out, in documentation..

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html